# Calling a macro

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c

I have the following macro:

```
#define testMethod(a, b) \
        if (a.length > b.length) \
            return a; \
        return b;
```

When I try to call it with:

```
NSString *s = testMethod(@"fir", @"sec");
```

I get an error:

> `"Excepted ";" at end of declaration"`

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if` is a statement, not an expression. It can't `return` a value like that.

You probably mean:

```
#define testMethod(a, b) ((a).length > (b).length ? (a) : (b))
```

The extra parenthesis around the arguments on the right side are common, and are there to protect you against unexpected precendence-related incidents.

Also note that because the above is pre-processed by doing textual replacement, it will probably construct more objects than the equivalent function would.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the macro within expressions, it should be defined as an expression itself, not as a group of statements. You end up with a syntax error because the macro is literally substituted, and statements are not allowed within another statement.

GCC has an extension called "statement expressions" that can help you achieve this, but it is non-standard:

```
#define testMethod(a, b) ({ \
    typeof(a) result = (a).length > (b).length ? (a) : (b); \
    result; \
})
```

Actually, in your case none of this is needed because the statements can be easily converted to an expression:

```
#define testMethod(a, b) ((a).length > (b).length ? (a) : (b))
```

Comment: +1, But there would be an even better variant: by using the `typeof` extension of gcc you could first evaluate `a` and `b` once, and then just evaluate the expression at the end of the `})`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use the return statement... try to use the following code

```
#define testMethod(a,b)  ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

may this will help you..